# Spring Reactive webclient fails to compile when using .bodyToFlux(new ParameterizedTypeReference<>) with "compiler message file broken"

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, spring-webclient

I am working on a small code snippet that needs to:

- Call an specific endpoint that contains pagination
- Get the list returned and put it into a flux of lists
- Postprocess this data

However, when i try to build the code, i am getting the following error message:

```
compiler message file broken: key=compiler.misc.msg.bug arguments=11.0.10, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$FlowAnalyzer.visitApply(Flow.java:1235)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1634)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$BaseAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:398)
        ...........
```

Code:

```
        WebClient client = WebClient.create();
        

        Flux<List<CustomerData>> data = Flux.just();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 32; i++) {
            int a = i;
            data = data.concatWith(client
                    .get()
                    .uri("apiurl/"+ i)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToFlux(new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
                    }));
        }
```

I'm not really sure what is happening, but i know for sure that the problematic line is `.bodyToFlux(new ParameterizedTypeReference<>()`.

When explicitly set the type to `.bodyToFlux(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<CustomerData>>()`, it works.
Why does it work when I explicitly add the type to `ParameterizedTypeReference`? My IDE suggested to remove it due to it being unnecessary.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, running on Java 11.

Tried restarting the IDE, the computer, updating the IDE, cleaning caches, invalidate caches and restart Intellij.

Comment: By using `List<CustomerData>`, you would get a `Flux<List<CustomerData>`. But you could use `bodyToFlux(CustomerData.class)` to get back a `Flux<CustomerData>` directly. And if you want all your objects in a single list, you can chain with a call to `collectList()`, which will return a `Mono<List<CustomerData>>`

Comment: @amanin the endpoint i need to call returns a `List<CustomerData`>, so as far as i know i need to consume it as `Flux<List<CustomerData>>` instead of `Flux<CustomerData>`

Comment: A flux is *0..n* emitted elements. An HTTP response body containing a JSON list of elements should be mappable to either a `Mono<List<Element>>` or a `Flux<Element>`. Note that `Flux<List<Element>>` might also work, but it is not clear then if you get a flux emitting a single List (which would be approximately equivalent to a mono), or if the response list is chunked in arbitrary batches.